# Can any one simplify this query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

```
      FirstCity   Secondcity Distance RoadName  RoadStatus
         008        007       4.600    A4       Good
         008        020       4.400    A4       Good
         005        008       4.300    A3       Good
```

I want to select rows for a particular City ID from the first city or from  the second city.Furthermore assume my city ID is 006. 
I want all the records which are having either of city number to be 006. 
But I don't want the 006 to be displayed. I want only the other city number of the record no matter from which column it is with Distance, roadName and Road Status. 
What I have tried is this.

```
    SELECT * FROM DirectNodes
    WHERE FirstCity='008' OR SecondCity='008';
```

it gives me all the five columns. I want only the other city number of the records having 008 without 008. My output should look like this.

```
                City    Distance RoadName  RoadStatus
                007       4.600    A4       Good
                020       4.400    A4       Good
                005       4.300    A3       Good
```

can anyone tell me how to achieve this.

Comment: What means: "it gives me all the four records"? I can see only 3 records in your example?

Comment: @Jens Edited. Hope you can understand it now.

Comment: @Jens If you execute the `SELECT` statement mentioned, you will get FOUR records... But he expected only 3 records...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Select case when firstcity = '008' then secondcity else firstcity end 'City',
       Distance,Roadname,Roadstatus
from   table
where (firstcity= '008' or secondcity ='008')
```

Comment: Then approve the answer by ticking it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT   CASE FirstCity WHEN '008' THEN SecondCity ELSE FirstCity END AS City,
         Distance, RoadName, RoadStatus
FROM     DirectNodes
WHERE    FirstCity = '008' OR SecondCity = '008'
```

Comment: Why do you use an Insert statement.. Azar 's query is working fine.

Comment: I worked out example based on your requirement(I mentioned clearly `I tried` before the example... ). The first statement is the answer and also there is no WHERE condition required. You can try..

Comment: It gives all the records, not only the records having 008 but also the other records too, but it has omitted the 008 in the records which have 008

Comment: Based on your example, I created the query... I thought in all the rows either FirstCity or SecondCity will have the value '008'. Then for your case `WHERE` condition required... I will update the answer